# Noise from CPFSK

Tags: fsk, java

I am programmatically generating a CPFSK encoding, and between shifting from two frequencies, there is extra noise generated by my speaker. For instance, going from 18375hz to 18900hz, there is extra noise. I am changing frequency at the point where the 18375 hz sinusoidal is at 0, and beginning at 0 for the 18900hz sinusoidal. The sample is played at 44.1kHz, and each sinusoidal is sampled 42 times before the next point is 0. Is this too rapid of a change in frequency? Thanks!

Edit:

I should add a better example here. I tried using a memoryless CPFSK known as Sunde FSK. If you choose two frequencies which are separated by 1/T, where T is the symbol length, then you should have a memoryless FSK. So, T=42/44100, and f1 = 18900 and f2 = 19950, this should fulfill these requirements. I still have a audible tone generated when I do this, so is there any suggestions as to how to make this inaudible using these frequencies?

Here is a plot of a transition from 18900hz to 19950hz. The transition occurs at point 42, and point 43 is the beginning of the 19950hz wave:

[image]

I think one of the issues is just a rapid change in frequency, but I could be wrong. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: A continuous-phase frequency-shift-keyed (CPFSK) signal maintains phase _continuity_ so that if $t$ denotes the instant of transition from one frequency to another, then if at $t^-$ the signal is $\cos(2\pi(18375)t + \theta)$, then the signal at time $t^+$ is $\cos(2\pi(18900)t + \phi)$ where $\phi$ is obtained from the equality $$2\pi(18375)t + \theta = 2\pi(18900)t + \phi.$$ Choosing a time instant where one sinusoid is $0$ and switching to the other sinusoid at that instant does not necessarily work.

Comment: I see the error now, thank you! If you made this a comment I could close the question.

Comment: Not sure if this will fix anything. Just tried it and there is still an audible tone.

Comment: Probably should add an example. There are Sunde FSK which are memoryless FSK. So, if you choose two frequencies such that they are separated by 1/T, the FSK should be a CPFSK. If you choose T=42/44100 and frequencies 18900 and 19950, this should be fine as they are seperated by 1050hz. I still have noise generated, however.

Comment: Your $\Delta f$ is obviously OK. There must be some other bug somewhere. You should plot the signals you generate, there must be some visible problem at the transition point.

Comment: If you are _alternating_ between the two tones at each transition point (instead of the choice being dictated by the "data bit", that is, you could have occasional runs of several symbol intervals with the same frequency), then you have, in effect, created a periodic signal with fundamental frequency $525$ Hz. One can sometimes _hear_ a fundamental even if only harmonics are present, since it is the brain that interprets the neural impulses delivered to it from the ear.

Comment: I'll plot the signal. The tone that is played is definitely audible, not due to the periodic wave. If I play a 18900hz sine wave for a few periods, I do not hear anything. When played with an interleaved 19950hz sine wave, a very loud tone is produced.

Comment: For what you are claiming to do, I don't think your picture looks correct. $$44,100/42 = 1050, 18900/1050 = 18, 19950/1050 = 19$$ and so, between $x[0]$ and $x[42]$ you should have $18$ or $19$ periods of one or the other sin function with both $x[0]$ and $x[42]$ having value $0$ exactly. $x[42]$ looks like it is $0$ but $x[0]$ does not.  Is my observation correct?

Comment: This is indexed from 1, not 0, so I assume you mean x[1] and x[43]. Not sure how they are not both 0. x[1] is definitely 0

Comment: You know that plot is really not representative of the signal, right?  You'd be better off viewing it in an audio editor that shows the interpolated waveform: http://flic.kr/p/7RLg74

Answer (score 1):

I think what you hear is probably some type of aliasing because your sampling frequency is too low given the FSK signal you're using. If you look at the plot you see that you do not get a constant envelope as you should. This is due to the relatively low sampling frequency. The maximum carrier frequency is almost 20kHz, and the upper limit of the FSK spectrum is not simply determined by the maximum carrier frequency, but it's higher due to the shifting between the two frequencies.

You could try (at least one of) the following:

- use much lower carrier frequencies, just to check if the (extra) tone you hear disappears. Of course you'll hear the two carriers then, but hopefully no other artifacts.
- use your original carriers but at first use a very high sampling rate, i.e. generate your signals with many more samples per period. Then use a digital lowpass filter at this high sampling frequency with a cut-off frequency of around 20kHz, and then downsample your signal to 44.1kHz. Then send the signal to your speakers and let us know how it sounds.

Answer (score 1):

With things indexed from $1$ instead of $0$, $x(t)$ a sinusoid of frequency $18900$ Hz
followed by a sinusoid of frequency $19950$ Hz with each tone lasting for $42/441000$ seconds and a sampling interval of $T = 1/44100$ seconds, you sample values should be
$$x[n] = \begin{cases}
\sin\left(2\pi (18900)(n-1)T\right), &1 \leq n \leq 43,\\
\sin\left(2\pi (19950)(n-1)T\right), &43 \leq n \leq 85, 
\end{cases}$$
where $x[43]$ has been defined twice, but since
$$18900\times 42/44100 = 18, ~~ 19950\times 42/44100 = 19$$
we have $x[43] = 0$ either way. In fact, $x[43]$ is the switching point where
the first sinusoid ends (after $18$ periods) and the second sinusoid begins. The
second sinusoid continues for $19$ periods and ends at $x[85]$.
Thus, $x[85]$ must also be $0$.  In your figure,
$x[43]$ appears to be $0$ while $x[85]$ is not shown. However, $x[84] < 0$ seems
nearly comparable in magnitude to $x[65]$ and since $x[66] > 0.5$, one might
expect that $x[85] > 0$. So, could you extend your plot by one more point and
verify that $x[85]=0$ as it should be?

Comment: This is incorrect...as I've said these two frequencies are plotting correctly. x[85] means t=84, and that point will be 0. I'm pretty sure the issue is the rapid change in frequency. Gaussian filters are supposed to eliminate some out of band noise.

Comment: @Batman "... and that point will be $0$." Could you _verify_ instead of _assert_ that $x[85]$ "will be" $0$? And what is the relationship of all this to the $18375$ Hz mentioned in the first paragraph of your answer?